# Where is the APU fuel pump on the A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, fuel-systems, apu

I'm looking for APU fuel pump location for A320 aircraft series. I'll be much appreciated if you provide a link to some images, schemes.

Answer (score 8):

According to the image below it seems that the APU fuel pump at the aft side of the center fuel tank.

[image: A320 APU Fuel Pump Location]

And this is the view from inside the center fuel tank looking aft:

[image]
([instagram.com](https://www.instagram.com/p/BmLeg-TANHf))

Note the pump still draws fuel from the left line, and not the center tank, it activates automatically if the left side engine fuel pumps don't provide the required pressure.

Comment: thank you! Really appreciate it. 
I mean the APU has its own fuel pump somewhere on APU assembly.
Or it's only near crossfeed valve? Is there fuel pump on APU under the tail?

Comment: @VictorChernobay, there is no point in having a pump in the tail, because that is too high. Liquid pumps are generally pretty bad at pumping gases, so they need to be below the level of the liquid to start—otherwise they'd be full of air and they can't suck the fuel in in such case—which means near the bottom of the tank.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the high pressure fuel pump mounted on the APS3200 accessory gearbox, you can not find a dedicated fuel pump mounting pad in the gearbox. The fuel pump is integral to the fuel control unit and they are mounted piggyback to and driven by the oil pump which is the one that has a mounting pad in the gearbox.

Comment: This strikes me as being contradictory to the (unsourced) image in the other answer. Do you have a source (with image if possible) for your information?